# Hiding cursor in Wayland

Tags: wayland, cursor

I know that X server can be started with `--nocursor` flag which hides mouse pointer, however I can't seem to find the same option for Wayland. I am running an electron app under (X)Wayland and mouse cursor is visible (can't hide it with css without moving the mouse - chromium bug). I have to add that the device is a tablet without any mouse attached to it, however `mouse0` is listed in `/dev/input/`. Any thoughts?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I found to solve this is to replace Adwaita icons. First I generated X11 cursor file with `xcursorgen` from transparent png file and then replaced all X11 files in `/usr/share/icons/Adwaita/cursors/`....